# Installshield Basic MSI project : Display logo dynamically from a folder which is not part of the installation

Tags: installshield

I am new to Installshield and I want to display the banners displayed in the dialogs during installation to be fetched dynamically from an external folder which resides in the path of the setup.exe (not part of the installation) using Installshield Basic MSI project.

[image: Run time includes a MyLogo folder next to setup.exe]

I tried specifying the “File Name” for the banner bitmaps in the dialog as `<SETUPEXEDIR>\MyLogo\Test.bmp`. But this gives an error as “File not found. Error streaming file to binary table.” when the project is built.
Is there a way possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer requires that the images are baked into the .msi file in order to display them (it saves the bits, not the name, in the [Binary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/binary-table)), so it's very reasonable to summarize this as not supported.

As a possible workaround (one I'm uncertain whether it can work), it's feasible that a custom action could write temporary records to the [Binary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/binary-table) or [Control table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368044) that containing the image found at run time. Note that this sort of custom action is somewhere between [admitting failure](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/8/17/zataoca-custom-actions-are-generally-an-admission-of-failure/) and a [semi-custom action](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/07/01/semi-custom-actions/). Furthermore finding the image, dealing with incorrect image sizes, determining which dialog boxes need the added image Binary or Control record, and possibly deleting an existing Binary or Control record, are left as exercises for an eager reader.